# QWebChannel: crash on construction when running outside of QtCreator

Tags: qtwebengine, qt5.7, qtwebchannel

When I try to run my programm **outside** the QtCreator, the code crashes, when `new QWebChannel(this)` is called. I already checked DLL dependencies, but can't find the difference between running it from within the IDE and outside of it.

```
MyView::MyView() : ui(new Ui::MyView) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    view = new QWebEngineView(this);

    channel = new QWebChannel(this); // crash at this line

    ui->content->addWidget(view);
    connect(view, &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, this, &MyView::finishLoading);
    view->page()->setWebChannel(channel);
    channel->registerObject("controller", this);
    view->load(QUrl("qrc:///res/index.html"));
}
```

In the project file I added `QT += webengine webenginewidgets webchannel`. Are there any other dependencies I may forgot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `windeployqt.exe` copies all necessary dependencies (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). Seames like some other resources nedded where causing the crash.